# Trying to to create an appearing image when clicking on a button, and close it when clicking outside

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, streamlit

I'm actually practicing for the first time with Streamlit and Javascript, and i'm struggling on creating an images gallery, when clicking a button, and closing it when clicking outside of it. I suppose it's a pretty nooby mistake, but i can't solve it..If someone could help, thank's by advance !

I've tried to integrate Javascript directly through streamlit library using markdown method, but something is wrong directly in my javascript and i don't know what.

```
import streamlit as st
from PIL import Image
import base64
from io import BytesIO

def main():
    st.title("Sliding Image App")

    # Check if the user has clicked on the image button
    is_clicked = st.button("️ Show Image", key="image_button")

    # Display the image or close it based on the click
    if is_clicked:
        show_image()

def show_image():
    # Path to your image file
    image_path = r"C:\Users\jdslo\OneDrive\Bureau\website\langor_seq06_Sh250.png"

    # Open the image using PIL
    original_image = Image.open(image_path)

    # Resize the image to a smaller size, e.g., 1920x1080
    target_size = (1920, 1080)
    original_image.thumbnail(target_size)

    # Convert the resized image to a base64-encoded string
    buffered = BytesIO()
    original_image.save(buffered, format="PNG")
    image_base64 = base64.b64encode(buffered.getvalue()).decode("utf-8")

    # Maximum height for the image
    max_image_height = "70vh"

    # Custom HTML and CSS to create a sliding image from the center
    html_code = f"""
        <style>
            .popup {{
                display: none;
            }}
            .popup.open {{
                display: block;
            }}
            .blocker {{
                position: fixed;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                right: 0;
                content: ' ';
                background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            }}
            .popup .contents {{
                border: 1px solid #ccc;
                border-radius: 5px;
                width: 80vw;
                height: {max_image_height};
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: center;
                background: #FFF;
                position: fixed;
                top: 50%;
                left: 50%;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                z-index: 9999;
                animation: slideIn 1s forwards;
            }}
            .popup .contents img {{
                max-height: {max_image_height};
                max-width: 100%;
            }}

            @keyframes slideIn {{
                from {{ transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0); }}
                to {{ transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1); }}
            }}
        </style>

        <div class="popup open" id="sliding-image-container">
            <div class="blocker" onclick="closeImage()"></div>
            <div class="contents" onclick="stopPropagation(event)">
                <img class="sliding-image" src="data:image/png;base64,{image_base64}" alt="Sliding Image">
            </div>
        </div>

        <script>
            function closeImage() {{
                var slidingImageContainer = document.querySelector('.popup');
                slidingImageContainer.classList.remove('open');
                setTimeout(function() {{
                    slidingImageContainer.style.display = 'none';
                }}, 1000);
            }}

            function stopPropagation(event) {{
                event.stopPropagation();
            }}

            document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {{
                var slidingImageContainer = document.querySelector('.popup');
                if (!slidingImageContainer.contains(event.target)) {{
                    closeImage();
                }}
            }});
        </script>
    """

    st.markdown(html_code, unsafe_allow_html=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

- You should avoid using `stopPropagation`. Any 3rd party code on your app or even your own should always, at any point be notified of events happening in the app environment. Instead use `evt.target.closest("selector")` in order to detect where the Event propagated from.
- Avoid the use of inline `on*` attributes handlers. JS should be in one place only and that's the respective SCRIPT file or tag. Use Element.addEventListener() instead
- Make smart use of data-* attributes in a way that `data-popup` can close any currently opened popup and if has a selector like `data-popup="#popup-image-1"` it will open it
- No need to use CSS animation. Simply toggle a `.open` and use CSS `transition`

Here's an example that even uses multiple popups and buttons:

```js
// DOM helpers:
const el = (sel, par = document) => document.querySelector(sel);
const els = (sel, par = document) => document.querySelectorAll(sel);

const popup = (popupId) => {
  el(".popup.open")?.classList.remove("open"); // Close any opened 
  popupId && el(popupId).classList.add("open");
};

els("[data-popup]").forEach((elBtn) => {
  elBtn.addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
    if (evt.target.closest(".popup-content")) return;
    popup(elBtn.dataset.popup);
  });
});
```

```css
.popup {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  z-index: 999;
  top:0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity 0.4s, visibility 0.4s;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);

  &.open {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
  }
}

.popup-content {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #fff;
  margin: auto;
  transition: scale 0.8s;
  padding: 5px;
  scale: 0;
  
  .popup.open & {
    scale: 1;
  }

  img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 80vw;
    max-height: 80vh;
    object-fit: contain;
  }
}
```

```html
<button data-popup="#popup-image-1">Open image 1</button>
<button data-popup="#popup-whatever">Open whatever</button>

<div class="popup" id="popup-image-1" data-popup>
  <div class="popup-content">
    <img class="sliding-image" src="https://picsum.photos/id/235/800/600" alt="Sliding Image">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="popup" id="popup-whatever" data-popup>
  <div class="popup-content">
    <img class="sliding-image" src="https://picsum.photos/id/130/600/800" alt="Sliding Image">
  </div>
</div>
```

PS: in case you'll need to open dynamically a specific popup, just call:

```js
popup("#somePopupId");
```